# What exactly does "git show --show-signature" verify?

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, git

After cloning a remote git repository and issuing `git show --show-signature`, it says the signature is good. Then I changed some files and tested the same command, and it still says the signature is good.

What exactly does the above command check? What is the correct way to verify the cloned git is what is meant by the developer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git show --show-signature` does exactly what it says in its manpage:

> --show-signature
>
> Check the validity of a signed commit object by  passing the signature to gpg --verify and show the output.

You must have imported a repo author's public key before so that `GPG`
can know where to look for it. You need to read up on a tutorial to
learn how `GPG` works to fully understand how it works.

Now for the second part of your question, `git show` without an
explicit commit SHA-1 or object name in general works on current
`HEAD`. If you just modified some files in your working copy but
didn't commit the changes then HEAD and all other commits in your
repository will stay the same, therefore `git show --show-signature`
will show you exactly the same as it would after a fresh cloning of
the repository. If you'd decide to commit your changes you will move
your `HEAD` one commit up but won't modify previous HEAD so `git show --show-signature HEAD^` will still show everything is ok.

Comment: You said: `git show without an explicit commit SHA-1 or object name in general works on current HEAD.` Where should I look for SHA-1 or object name? And what is the syntax to use them? I also did not understand the last part of your answer: `if you'd decide to commit your changes you will move your HEAD one commit up but won't modify previous HEAD so git show --show-signature HEAD^ will still show everything is ok.`

Comment: Do you know `Git`? `SHA-1` is a hex string shown at the top of every commit in `git log`. It ambiguously identifies every commit in a repository. `HEAD` is a synonym for a currently checked-out `SHA-1`. `git show` can also other objects apart from `SHA-1`, see `man gitrevisions`. `HEAD^` means a previous commit.

Comment: Thank you. So one last time: If I clone a repository and then check its authenticity by `git show --show-signature` and receive a good signature, can I be sure that what I have received is what is meant by the developer and has not been tempered by the server, etc.?

Comment: By using `git show --show-signature` you can only check that the *last* commit in the repository has been signed by the author unless, of course, his key has been stolen. Use `git log --show-signature` to check all commits.

Answer (score 0):

Commits don't change. `git status` will report on the status of your worktree; `git show` is for showing you repository content.